# React-Native : error while import component to App.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Getting error while import the default class from the components 
 using **expo**, I search for this error but did not resolve the solution, the component returns object.

`type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)` **but got: object**

Error :

```
12:19:03: Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check your code at registerRootComponent.js:35.
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:33)
    in RCTView (at View.js:60)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
    in RCTView (at View.js:60)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:32)
```

**App.js**

```
import Login from './app/components/login';
```

**app/components/login/index.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';

export default class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
             <Text>Login</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `App.js` use default import for `Login` component. Also, export a root component from `App.js`

```
import React from "react";
import Login from './app/components/login';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Login/>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Its nothing, have one line of import.